# Cannot read property of undefined when assigning websocket message data

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm creating a chat application using Ratchet Websocket. I followed their Hello World tutorial here: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

When I try to assign the data of received messages through a global function or variable, I get the error:

"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'recievedMessage' of undefined
at onMessage_callback (dashboard.component.ts:32)
at WebSocket.conn.onmessage [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYmessage]"

I have read many other posters with the same issues but I cant figure out how to get their answers to work like they say. I am trying to add sent and received messages to a global array so I can display them all in a chat list. I know my problem has something to do with the scope of `this.conn.onmessage=function(e)` but this is the first time I have used websockets or seen this syntax.
Why cant I call `this.recievedMessage(data);` from `function onMessage_callback(data);`?

Similar question (It even mentions you can assign data from callback to a global variable but this does not work for me): [WebSocket returns undefined in code but not in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615298/websocket-returns-undefined-in-code-but-not-in-console)

I know all my backend client/chat php is working correctly due to the console showing messages for different connections.

typescript code:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  conn:WebSocket;
  messageDisplay:any[] = ["Welcome To Chat"]
  message: string;

  constructor() {}
  

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    this.conn.onopen = function(e) {
      console.log("Connection established!");
    };
  
    this.conn.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log(e.data);
      onMessage_callback(e.data);
    };

    function onMessage_callback(data){
      this.recievedMessage(data);
    }
  }

  recievedMessage(message){
    this.messageDisplay.push(message);
  }



  sendMessage(message){
    this.conn.send(message);
      this.messageDisplay.push(message);
      console.log(this.messageDisplay);
  }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context for `this` changed when you are inside another function (onMessage_callback), so `this` is no longer referring to the parent object at this point.

TO use the reference `this` to the main class you must wrap this reference in another local variable (in this example, `self`)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    var self = this;
    this.conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    this.conn.onopen = function(e) {
      console.log("Connection established!");
    };
  
    this.conn.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log(e.data);
      onMessage_callback(e.data);
    };

    function onMessage_callback(data){
      self.recievedMessage(data); 
    }
  }
```

Este articulo explica con ejemplos como funciona el `binding`
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind

Comment: Thank you it worked! I was unaware that the context of this could change. I thought it always referred to the top level variables in a class.